# How can I make "bind" command to work in sh shell

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

How can I make the next script to run when I'm using sh shell:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

bind '^[[3'=prefix-2
bind '^[[3~'=delete-char-forward
bind '^[[1'=prefix-2
bind '^[[1~'=beginning-of-line
bind '^[[4'=prefix-2
bind '^[[4~'=end-of-line
```

[image: bind in sh]

Comment: The `sh` shell lacks `source` but a lone dot (aka period, full stop) does the same thing. Since the `bind` command isn't supported, either, this is completely tangential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind` is a bash command, not an sh command. If you aren't using bash, the `bind` command won't be available.

Depending on the platform, `sh` may be one of several shells. They all provide a [common core](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/xcu.html) for scripting. Plain `sh` hardly has any convenient features for interactive use; in particular, plain `sh` has no notion of key bindings.

On some systems, `sh` is bash (which runs in a compatibility mode when invoked as `sh`) and uses the readline library for command line edition and supports the key bindings through the `bind` builtin. Other systems use leaner shells such as dash or ksh which are faster for executing scripts. If you want a decent command line interface, don't call `sh`.

Note that the script you wrote has no effect when run (except to print warnings that the `bind` command is pointless in a non-interactive shell). A file containing only key binding definitions cannot be a useful standalone executable, only a shell snippet. So the shebang at the top is not useful.

Comment: Thanks for doing some light in this sense. Do you know any alternatives to `bind` that can be used in a sh shell?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu There is no alternative: `sh` (at least the flavor you have) doesn't have any notion of key binding. What you can do is go through a generic wrapper such as [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/rlwrap.html), but it's not nearly as nice as using a shell with proper key bindings.

Comment: Ok, good to know and not to try anything else in vain. Thanks again.

Comment: I tend to use such useless shebangs at the top in the sourced files, only for syntax highlighting in the editor. As such it's added in a comment & I don't want to add a `.sh` extension just for syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 1):

`bind` is not available in `sh`. Modify `~/.inputrc` if you want to change readline bindings.

Comment: I can see, `sh: 2: surce: not found`. But my question is if there are any possibilities to make that script to work in sh. Or, maybe you can explain how to make those changes in `~/.inputrc` file (I don't have this file in my system). Thanks

Comment: See the `readline(3)` man page for details on the configuration file.

Comment: Repeat and rephrase: If your `sh` is a proper Bourne shell, it might simply lack the support for this.

Comment: The "Key Bindings" section of the [readline manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline+3) has many examples. Try one, and if it works, take it from there.

Comment: The file is `.inputrc` but, as stated already, it is also possible that your `sh` lacks `readline` support, and hence ignores this file.